# Any pdf reader which can email the current page?

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-viewer

I use a Surface tablet running Windows. If the page I am reading has some important info, I want to email it to myself. Looking for a pdf reader that can easily email the current page. Not email the whole file.
One that can do it with ease with a pen.